# Can you run Target Designer for NT 4.0 on an XP box?

Tags: windows-xp, compatibility, windows-nt

I'm trying to run Microsoft Windows NT Embedded 4.0 [Target Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms854318(WinEmbedded.4).aspx) on a Windows XP system, but when I try to build, I get errors. Have you ever done this, and if so, is there a trick to getting it to work?

The best clue I've found so far from Microsoft is that the [Development System Hardware Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms853895(WinEmbedded.4).aspx) document includes "Windows NT 4.0 Service Pack 4 or later," but I don't know if XP is considered a valid "or later" for NT 4.0.

When I try to build an image by running Target Designer in Windows NT 4.0 or Windows 2000 compatibility mode, I get this error during Building Registry / Adding component parameters:

```
ERROR: Couldn't get security error = 5
```

When I run it normally under XP, the error that comes up during Building Registry / Binding Network is:

```
ERROR: Failed to bind network - Incorrect function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options (which you may have already tried);

1. Right click on the link to the
   Target Designer executable and
   select properties, then select the
   Compatibility tab and set 'Run this
   program in compatibility mode for:'
   and choose 'Windows NT (SP5)' from
   the dropdown. You should be able to
   run TD then.
2. If that does not work, download Virtual PC from
   Microsoft (free) and create a new
   Virtual Machine for Windows NT (you
   can get the ISO images for NT from
   MSDN but you need a valid account,
   otherwise use your CD Roms for NT).

I hope that helps.

Ryan